# How to change colour when I click a button in guizero Python 3?

Tags: python, user-interface, guizero

So I have written this piece of code in python3 guizero to change colour to red when I click the button I created. But whatever I do it's not working! I am not sure what I did wrong but it just won't work (I used Visual Studio Code but it didn't give me any errors or say the code was wrong.) So I figured this will be the best place to come.
This is the code I wrote:

```
from guizero import *

red = 255,0,0

def cl_ch():
    if mahe_pushbutton.text == "Push":
        mahe_text.text_colour = red
    else:
        print("Not working")

mahe_app = App(title = "TEST")

mahe_text = Text(mahe_app, text = "test test", font = "Orbitron", size = 20)

mahe_textbox = TextBox(mahe_app, width = 50)



mahe_pushbutton = PushButton(mahe_app, command=cl_ch, text = "Push")

mahe_pushbutton.width = 60

mahe_pushbutton.height = 3



mahe_app.display()
```

Thanks if you are able to help!

Comment: You misspelled color

Comment: Its american? lol

Comment: @PurpleLlama Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi I've only just started looking at Guizero, my programming skills aren't very advanced but
This should make the text red when you press the button but stays red afterwards.

```
from guizero import *

red = 255,0,0

def cl_ch():        

    mahe_text.text_color = "red"


mahe_app = App(title = "TEST")

mahe_text = Text(mahe_app, text = "test test", font = "Orbitron", size = 20)

mahe_textbox = TextBox(mahe_app, width = 50)

mahe_pushbutton = PushButton(mahe_app, command=cl_ch, text = "Push")

mahe_pushbutton.width = 60

mahe_pushbutton.height = 3

mahe_app.display()
```

This next bit crudely resets the text to black after about a second or 1000 miliseconds

```
from guizero import *

red = 255,0,0

def cl_ch():        

    mahe_text.text_color = "red"
    
def cl_ch_2():

    mahe_text.text_color = "black"

mahe_app = App(title = "TEST")

mahe_text = Text(mahe_app, text = "test test", font = "Orbitron", size = 20)

mahe_textbox = TextBox(mahe_app, width = 50)

mahe_text.repeat(1000,cl_ch_2) # a kind of counter that reset the colour back to black

mahe_pushbutton = PushButton(mahe_app, command=cl_ch, text = "Push")

mahe_pushbutton.width = 60

mahe_pushbutton.height = 3

mahe_app.display()
```

When you push the button it runs the cl_ch function so you just need to update that one attribute or method of the Text which is the text_color.

I can't figure out how to set it back though so I just coded a repeat text after 1000 miliseconds as a reset.

hope that helped

Answer (score 0):

```
from guizero import *

red = (255,0,0)



mahe_app = App(title = "TEST")

mahe_text = Text(mahe_app, text = "test test", font = "Orbitron", size = 20)


def cl_ch():
    mahe_text.text_color = red

def refresh():
    mahe_text.text_color = "black"



mahe_textbox = TextBox(mahe_app, width = 50)



mahe_pushbutton = PushButton(mahe_app, command=cl_ch, text = "Push")

mahe_pushbutton.width = 60

mahe_pushbutton.height = 3


mahe_app.repeat(250, refresh)
mahe_app.display()
```

You need red = (255,0,0) instead of red = 255,0,0
the function must be declared after the Text or receive the Text as a entry arg.
If you never change the text in the button, remove the condition because it will always enter in the if and never in the else.
I didn't know if you wanted the text to turn black again so i createda function that puts the text black and used the method repeat from the App to put the text black every 250 milisseconds